# jq how to call function by value in variable

Tags: jq

here i defined 2 functions and call the second directly:

```
$ jq -n 'def f1: "here f1" ; def f2: "here f2"; f2'
"here f2"
```

can i define a variable and call the function name contained in the value of that variable?  for example:

```
$ jq --arg fp f1 -n 'def f1: "here f1" ; def f2: "here f2"; "fp is \($fp)"'
"fp is f1"
```

I want to call the function that is defined by the fp variable. so the result would be
"fp is here f1"

Comment: When you ran your second example, you didn't get `"fp is f1"` ?

Answer (score 0):

> can i define a variable and call the function name contained in the value of that variable?

No. You’d have to write a dispatcher.

Comment: How would you write a dispatcher? `{ f1, f2 } as $d | $d["f2"]` doesn't work (since it calls `f1` and `f2` when building the object). Do you mean like a series if-elseif?

Comment: In short - yes.  Do you think it's worthwhile mentioning shell-based string-interpolation as a theoretical alternative?